# publishactions scope is not working please check and let me update if any permissions

Tags: node.js

Publish actions for facebook graph api for posting messge or vedio was not posted. In version 3.3 posting any message or video we have used post api me/feed with message details till not posting. Is there any update from posting info for accessing those permissions?

Below I am getting error when I am posting information:

> (#200) If posting to a group, requires app being installed in the group, and \
>             either publish_to_groups permission with user token, or both manage_pages \
>             and publish_pages permission with page token; If posting to a page, \
>             requires both manage_pages and publish_pages as an admin with \
>             sufficient administrative permission
>
> please check and update permissions.

10202807393225701/feed

```
var FB = require('fb');
FB.setAccessToken('access_token');

var body = 'My first post using facebook-node-sdk';
FB.api('me/feed', 'post', { message: body }, function (res) {
  if(!res || res.error) {
    console.log(!res ? 'error occurred' : res.error);
    return;
  }
  console.log('Post Id: ' + res.id);
});
```